# When partitioning results can I include the results of a quartile breakdown?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to partition my data based on ranking. For example say I have:

```
Company revenue industry
a        100    tech
b        75     tech
c        50     tech
d        50     retail
e        35     tech
```

I want to run a query to provide analytics based on partitions of the data.

```
with data as (
    select
        g.company,
        g.industry,
        g.countryname,
        c.revenue,
        ntile(4) over (partition by g.industry order by c.revenue) as quartile,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.industry ORDER BY c.revenue ASC) AS groupingNumRank,
        AVG(c.revenue) over (PARTITION BY g.industry) as industavg,
        ... and so on
```

As you can see I am partitioning by g.industry but I'd like to further partition the above data by quartiles.

I can add more items to the partition such as g.countryname, etc but I cannot add quartile to further partition the data by quartiles AND industry in my query.

Is it possible?

Comment: provide your expected output.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a subquery that calculates the quartile in the `FROM` clause of an outer query that then can use that value in a window clause.